# How to get a Line from a text file into a String C#

Tags: c#, text

I need to make something that can get a specific line number and get the information in it into a String. And I couldn't figure out how I can do that.

Does anybody have a sample code/example that solves this problem?

Comment: Any examples of it? Does it have a pattern? What have you tried?, visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i did not try anything, i did not know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use File.ReadAllText (or Lines it might be) and then split the text by newline into an array of strings.
Then you can index into that array.

Comment: so like public static int XPos = File.ReadAllLines(line number);?

Comment: could you give me an example? because i need a Specific Line to Be Read

Comment: Please @ArkadiuszBrzoza , put some effort into it. It is your home work. If you want to grade you have to learn. And to learn you have to try.